# Multiple repositories in the service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem, in my server project there are related entities with a one-to-many relationship, implemented through Entity Framework.
Classes:

```cs
public class University
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
    public University University { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class UniversityRepository : IUniversityRepository   
{       
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;        
    
    public UniversityRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)         
    {           
        this.dbContext = dbContext;         
    }       
    
    public async Task<int> Create(University entity)        
    {
        await dbContext.Universities.AddAsync(entity);          
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();             
        return entity.Id;       
    }   
}
```

Relationship of entities:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<University> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(b => b.Groups)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(g => g.UniversityId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

I don't fully understand how to add a new instance of the Group class. I have two repository classes for the database responsible for CRUD operations.
It turns out that in order to add a new instance of the Group class, I need to use two repositories in one service at once, because I need to assign values to the UniversityId, University fields and add an instance of the Group class to the Groups field of an instance of the University class (it is assumed that it exists because it is a strong entity)?
How many repositories can there be in the service intended for to access data from a database?
How many tables can be accessed from the same repository?
If I'm wrong, please explain why.

I tried to add several repositories to one service, but I don't understand if this is correct?

Comment: Why do you even need repositories? It is anti-pattern with EF Core.

Comment: Can you also show the repositories? And what your service looks like?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand how to attach the code, because I am a beginner on the site. Here is the code, the repositories differ only in the types of the input parameter.            `public class UniversityRepository : IUniversityRepository
 {
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

  public UniversityRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
  {
   this.dbContext = dbContext;
  }

  public async Task<int> Create(University entity)
  {
   await dbContext.Universities.AddAsync(entity);
   await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

   return entity.Id;
  }
 }`

Comment: @Pavka edit the question and add the code. The bug is the code itself though. EF Core's DbContext is a high-level *multi-entity* Unit-of-Work, it doesn't need any "repositories". What you posted isn't a repository either, it's a low-level CRUD class (Data Access Object is the official name) with broken transactions. You *don't* need multiple repositories at all.

Comment: The reason the code is buggy is because, as a Unit-of-Work, a DbContext already tracks *all* pending changes, to all the objects it tracks. When the time comes to commit the changes, `SaveChanges` will connect, persist *all* of them, in a single database transaction, in the correct order *and* fix up any relations, IDs, primary keys etc. To discard the changes, just dispose the contect or let DI do it for you. The CUD methods you posted break this because they save on every single modification which means 1) your Create can perform 42 DELETEs and 2) you can't roll back the changes any more

Comment: With EF Core, if you map both `UniversityId` and `University`, you doesn't need to set the `University` property when adding a new `Group`, simply set UniversityId and save the group via the `DbContext`. And also you doesn't need to add the new Group to the Groups collection of the University. On the other side if you already have the `University` object you could simply add a new Group to the parent and then call `SaveChanges`.